# Facebook Developer API iOS, age_range returns NULL

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Here's my code, what am I doing wrong here? Bear in mind that I'm using FBLoginView and the other strings returns actual valid results, just not age range. Thanks in advance, - Daniel

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

NSString *userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.objectID]; //objectID instead?
NSLog(@"userID = %@", userID);

NSString *nameFull = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.name];
NSLog(@"nameFull = %@", nameFull);

NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.first_name];
NSLog(@"firstName = %@", firstName);

NSString *middleName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.middle_name];
NSLog(@"middleName = %@", middleName);

NSString *lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.last_name];
NSLog(@"lastName = %@", lastName);

NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.link];
NSLog(@"link = %@", link);

NSString *gender = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [user objectForKey:@"gender"]];
NSLog(@"gender = %@", gender);

NSDictionary *ageRangeDict = [user objectForKey:@"user_age_range"];
NSString *ageRange = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",
                      [ageRangeDict objectForKey:@"min"],
                      [ageRangeDict objectForKey:@"max"]];

NSLog(@"ageRange = %@", ageRange);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
NSDictionary *ageRangeDict = [user objectForKey:@"user_age_range"];
```

To this:

```
NSDictionary *ageRangeDict = [user objectForKey:@"age_range"];
```

Reference: [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user)

Comment: I just tried it, and it still returns NULL in my log: ageRange = (null)-(null)

Comment: Try logging `NSLog(@"%@", user");` and see what keys it lists.

Comment: I just tried it and it lists everything from birthday to timezone keys but just not age_range, which is weird because it's a part of the permission @"public_profile", I'm calling.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure. My answer should work if you can get the correct data returned. Just try verifying that you're calling the Facebook API correctly.

Comment: yeah I just don't get it man.. I will set your answer as correct though anyway :) - Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Use "age_range" instead

according to the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user)